# How to specify which child terminal gets focus on terminator startup

Tags: command-line, gnome, terminator

I have a terminator layout which looks like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|     |  2  |
|  1  +-----+
|     |  3  |
+-----+-----+
```

When I start terminator, child terminal 3 receives focus.  Is there a config directive I can use either through the pref gui or in ~/.config/terminator/config which will give child term 1 initial focus on startup?

*EDIT*

The layout section in my config looks like this:

```
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      position = 0:0
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1920, 1030
    [[[child1]]]
      position = 960
      type = HPaned
      order = 0
      parent = child0
    [[[child3]]]
      position = 515
      type = VPaned
      order = 1
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child1
    [[[terminal5]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child3
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child3
```

Comment: As far as I in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/terminator_config.5.html) there is not a option for this, but you could set the focus to sloppy (or follow mouse, whatever it is in settings) so you don't have to select the left pane by clicking it.

Comment: What is the orer they appear (if you can see that).

Comment: I am not that familiar with terminator, but it would be quite easy to make it a launcher to 1. startup terminator 2. wait for the third window to appear 3. set focus on the first (or any other one from the order). would that be a solution?

Comment: Posted an answer. Please review, folks, lemme know what you think

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've been testing with your profile setup:
`nohup terminator -l TestProfile --command="xdotool key Ctrl+Tab;$SHELL"  & 2>/dev/null`

This command , ran from gnome-terminal, opens terminator with your specified layout, and executes two commands - `xdotool key Ctrl+Tab` and `$SHELL`. xdotool is an emulator for keyboard or mouse behavior, basically, and once the terminator starts, it emulates pressing Ctrl+Tab, which makes focus switch from window 3 to window 1. `$SHELL` environment variable then gets expanded to your shell (for example, for me it is /bin/mksh), and that way the window won't exit once xdotool command completes.

You can bind a script to a shortcut (full path to script) or create[.desktop](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) file (in your `~/.config/autostart` ) to launch this whole setup on startup. The script would have to go something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

terminator -l TestProfile --command="xdotool key Ctrl+Tab;$SHELL"  &
```

**Pros ?** Does exactly what you ask of it. If you'd want to focus on window 2, your `--command=` would look like `--command=xdotool key Ctrl+Tab;xdotool key Ctrl+Tab;$SHELL`, i.e., emulate pressing Ctrl+Tab twice.

**Cons**: need to install `xdotool`

and remember to make the script executable with `chmod +x`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do basically the same and came up with a solution using the terminal "order" setting in the config, after a bit of trial and error. In my case I have one terminal per tab and want to give initial focus to the first (leftmost) tab, which I achieved as follows:

It's not as simple as it should be because terminator seems to always leave focus at the last tab opened (the highest numbered terminal entry) so what you need to do is this. If your terminal configuration is currently:

```
[[[terminal2]]]
  order = 0
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-1
  type = Terminal
[[[terminal3]]]
  order = 1
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-2
  type = Terminal
[[[terminal4]]]
  order = 2
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-3
  type = Terminal
```

Then change it to:

```
[[[terminal2]]]
  order = 2
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-3
  type = Terminal
[[[terminal3]]]
  order = 1
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-2
  type = Terminal
[[[terminal4]]]
  order = 0
  parent = child1
  profile = Profile-1
  type = Terminal
```

You'll now end up with the same terminals in the same tabs, but the initial focus is now the left-most tab.

Note that if you have labels set in the child entries then don't change those - they still apply to the tabs left-to-right, as before the change.

I would imagine that the same solution can be applied for the original question's config with terminals in different child entries too.